# Google Maps in VisualForce problem

Tags: visualforce, google-map

I am new using VisualForce and this is the first time I'm using this technology. I have to use the google maps api in VF because of the limitations of LWC lightning-map.
My VisualForce looks like this:

```
    <apex:page controller="MapCECompleto_Controller">
    <head>
        <script src="{!googleMapsApi}"></script>
        <script>
            function initMap(){
                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                    zoom: 8,
                    center: {lat: 37.7749, lng: -122.4194}
                });
                
                //Iteramos sobre los datos del controler
                var lists = {!JSON.serialize(completeList)};
                
                for(var i = 0; i<lists.length; i++){
                    var iData = lists[i];
                    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
                    geocoder.geocode({'address': iData.Direccion}, function(result,status){
                        if(status == 'OK'){
                            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            position: results[0].geometry.location,
                            map: map,
                            title: iData.Name})
                        }else{
                            alert('Problem in: '+ status);
                        }
                    })
                }
            }
        
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="initMap()">
        aqui
        aqui1
        <div id="map" style="height: 500px"></div>
        aqui 2
    </body>
    </apex:page>
```

And my apex controller:

```apex
public class MapCECompleto_Controller {

    public static String GOOGLE_MAPS_API = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=';
    
    public static String getGoogleMapsApi(){
        String developerNameIntegracion = 'Google_' + Label.SalesforceOrg; //Google_dev
        
        String authToken = IntegracionHelperClass.getAuthToken(developerNameIntegracion);
        
        String googleMapsURLWithToken = GOOGLE_MAPS_API + authToken;
        System.debug('googleMapsURLWithToken ---- '+ googleMapsURLWithToken);
        
        return googleMapsURLWithToken;
    }
    public static List<Object> getCompleteList(){
        List<Object> recordsToReturn = new List<Object>();

        List<SObject1> listOne = [SELECT Id,Direccion__c, Estado__c, Name FROM SObject1];

        if(!listOne.isEmpty()){
            for(SObject1 iItem: listOne){
                if(iItem.Estado__c == HelperClass.ESTADO_ACTIVADO){
                    Map<String, Object> oneMap = new Map<String, Object>();
                    oneMap.put('Name', iItem.Name);
                    oneMap.put('Direccion', iItem.Direccion__c);
                    oneMap.put('Objeto', 'Object 1');
                    oneMap.put('Id',iItem.Id );

                    recordsToReturn.add(oneMap);
                }
            }
        }

        List<SObject2> listTwo =  [SELECT Id,EstadoSolicitud__c,Direccion__c,, Name,  FROM SObject2];

        if(!listTwo.isEmpty()){
            for(SObject2 iItem: listTwo){
                if(iItem.EstadoSolicitud__c == HelperClass.ESTADO_NUEVA || iItem.EstadoSolicitud__c == HelperClass.ESTADO_EN_GESTION){
                    Map<String, Object> twoMap = new Map<String, Object>();
                    twoMap.put('Name',iItem.Name );
                    twoMap.put('Direccion', iItem.Direccion__c);
                    twoMap.put('Objeto','Object 2');
                    twoMap.put('Id',iItem.Id );
                    recordsToReturn.add(twoMap);
                }
            }
        }

        List<SObject3> listThree = [SELECT Id,Direccion__c, Name FROM SObject3 LIMIT 3];
        if(!listThree.isEmpty()){
            for(SObject3 iItem: listThree){
                Map<String, Object> threeMap = new Map<String, Object>();
                threeMap.put('Name', iItem.Name);
                threeMap.put('Direccion',iItem.Direccion__c);
                threeMap.put('Objeto','Object 3');
                threeMap.put('Id',iItem.Id);
                recordsToReturn.add(threeMap);
            }
        }

        List<SObject4> listFour = [SELECT Id, Direccion__c, Name FROM SObject4 LIMIT 3];

        if(!listFour.isEmpty()){
            for(SObject4 iItem :listFour){
                Map<String, Object> fourthMap = new Map<String, Object>();
                fourthMap.put('Name', iItem.Name);
                fourthMap.put('Direccion',iItem.Direccion__c);
                fourthMap.put('Objeto','Object 4');
                fourthMap.put('Id',iItem.Id);
                recordsToReturn.add(fourthMap);
            }
        }

        System.debug('recordsToReturn ------ '+ recordsToReturn);
        return recordsToReturn;
    }  
   }
```

The thing is that the map is not being shown. I checked that the google maps api key is valid. I checked in the browse console and I am getting the following error Error: Unknown function JSON.serialize. Check spelling in the line

```
var accounts = {JSON.serialize(completeList)};
```

And also the error on initMap is not defined at onload

Could anybody help me? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The correct function to use JSON in javascript is JSON.stringify()